# How can we able to send query result csv to ftp folder through http?

Tags: apex, integration, rest-service, httprequest

```
public Class GenerateCSV {
    public GenerateCSV(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public List<batch__c> getcontact() {
          return [select Id,Name,Quote_line_item__c from batch__c LIMIT 20];
    }
    String endPoint = 'http://Tejdeep:889';
public void postDataToRemote(String name,String email,Integer age){
   performAction('POST',name,email,age);   
}
public void performAction(String method){
  Batch__c[] batches = [select Id,Name,Quote_line_item__c from batch__c LIMIT 20];       
             //Prepare http req
             HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
             req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
            req.setMethod(method);
              //query q=[select Id,Name,Quote_line_item__c from batch__c LIMIT 20];
                String JSONString = JSON.serialize(q);   


            req.setBody(JSONString);

            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

            System.debug(res.getBody());

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No they are independent protocols - FTP = File Transfer Protocol and HTTP = Hypertext Transfer Protocol.

FTP from Apex code is not directly supported. See the unimplemented idea [FTP from salesforce](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YdsWAAS) for some work-arounds and there are probably others essentially involving some external service (e.g. that accepts HTTP requests and forwards via FTP).